# How can I use Tuple<> to return value instead of using 'out' argument in method?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, heap-memory

I want to get the resulting value from void method using `Tuple<>`.

Small code sample:

```
XElement xRoot;
DirectoryInfo di;
XElement xResult;
AddXmlNode(xRoot, di, xResult);

void AddXmlNode(Tuple<XElement, DirectoryInfo, XElement> task)
{
    var xNode = (XElement)task.Item3;
    xNode = new XElement("dir1");
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong: new variable `xNode` now points to the same memory area of "managed heap" as `xResult` does? So if change value of `xNode` it affects `xResult` too. Right?

If I'm wrong, please explain how can I return value via `Tuple<>`

Comment: @Savanna can you check it, yes. However, the concepts underlying it are not always easy to understand, nor is the solution that gets what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, **yes** this line:

```
var xNode = (XElement)task.Item3;
```

Causes both elements to *point* at the same item in memory. This means that if you did this:

```
xNode.SomeProperty = "Bob";
```

Both references would get "Bob" if they subsequently accessed "SomeProperty". However, you write this:

```
xNode = new XElement("dir1");
```

This re-assigns *just* the `xNode` variable to a new object. They now point at two different objects. To get what you want, you would need to pass `xResult` by ref, which I don't think you can do with `Tuple`. Even if you can, it would be confusing and I wouldn't personally do it. The code you need is:

```
AddXmlNode(new Tuple<XElement, DirectoryInfo>(xRoot, di), ref xResult);

void AddXmlNode(Tuple<XElement, DirectoryInfo> task, ref XElement result)
{
    var xNode = (XElement)task.Item3;
    xNode = new XElement("dir1");
}
```

By the way, since `Tuple` is strongly typed, you shouldn't need the cast on your initial variable assignment of `xNode`, it should pick it up automatically.

Comment: thanks for explanation! But I need to pass only **one** argument to method (because I run it in different thread), that's why I use `Tuple<>`. Any advises?

Comment: @Andrew yes, don't do that! Passing by ref into a thread is just *asking* for trouble. Now you have a high likelihood of that variable being "fought over" by both threads, potentially assigning it, etc. I would rethink what you are doing, because you have a threading nightmare just waiting to happen with your setup.

Comment: @Andrew if you are doing this to avoid blocking the UI thread, you may consider using await/async or putting the whole operation on another thread (so you don't have to pass the stuff in).

Comment: according to my task, I have to implement multithreading without usage of `PLINQ, async/await` etc. Just manually work with threads. The method I'm trying to implement has to get two parameters (`XElement` and `DirectoryInfo`), but in a new thread I can run only methods of signature `void MyMethod(object arg){ }`, so I decided to put these two variables into `Tuple<XElement, DirectoryInfo>`. But I also need to return a value (of type `XElement`) from this method... And now I don't know how to do this. Btw, only one thread will work with this method, if this information helps :)

Comment: @Andrew If this is for school, I would ask your instructor why *this method* needs to be threaded. `AddXmlNode` does not seem to be a good candidate for a new thread (`CreateXmlDocument`, on the other hand, might be). In either case, your best bet is probably to raise a callback or event when you are done, and pass the filled object on it instead of modifying a parameter or using a return value.

Comment: it is for interview :) Thanks for detailed responses!